# How do I get Outlook (via Exchange) to accept Thunderbird/Lightning meeting requests?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, lightning, meetings

Lightning/1.0b1 addon to Thunderbird/3.0.4  has no problem accepting Meeting Requests sent from my network Outlook session.  However, Meeting Requests sent to an email address hosted on a POP server and to be delivered to my Outlook mailbox never seem to arrive in any fashion.  Nothing in my Outlook Inbox or Messages and nothing on my calendar or anything.

I was expecting at least a std email, perhaps with an *ics attachment file, to arrive just like regular Thunderbird-originated email does, but no dice.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?